# PHP: need explanation using [a-zA-Z0-9]

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I am new to PHP (not programming overall), and having problems with this simple line of code. I want to check whether some input field has been filled as anysymbolornumber@anysymbolornumber just for checking whether correct email was typed. I don't get any error, but the whole check system doesn't work. Here is my code and thanks!

```
  if ($email = "[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9]")
{
```

Comment: In PHP, you'll want to use double equals to compare two values (of any type) and triple equals to compare two values of the same type. In this case, what you've done is assigned variable `$email` the string `"[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9]"` and the if statement is not checking for equality, but rather if the variable assignment worked. If you want to use regex patterns, look up the PHP PCRE functions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since your new to php , i suggest you should buy a book or read an tutorial or two.

For email validation you should use filter_var an build in function that comes with with php 5.2 and up :

```
<?php
if(!filter_var("someone@example....com", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    echo("E-mail is not valid");
}else{
   echo("E-mail is valid");
}
?>
```

Comment: i knew about this function! uh, many libraries, few regexes.. well done!

Answer (score 4):

you can use other functions .. instead of regular expressions

```
if(filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
 echo "Valid email";
}else{
 echo "Not a valid email";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As correctly pointed out in the comments, the regex you are using isn't actually a very good way of validating the email. There are much better ways, but if you are just wanting to get a look at how regular expressions work, it is a starting point. I am not an expert in regex, but this will at least get your if statement working :)

```
if(preg_match("[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9]",$email)
{
    // Your stuff
}
```

Comment: That only matches three characters: one to the left of `@`, one to the right, and `@` itself.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to verify that an email address matches a certain pattern.  But you're not using the proper function. You probably want something like `preg_match( $pattern, $target )`.

Also, your regex isn't doing what you would want anyway.  In particular, you need some quantifiers, or else your email addresses will only be able to consist of one character ahead of the `@`, and one after.  And you need anchors at the beginning and end of the sequence so that you're matching against the entire address, not just the two characters closest to the `@`.

Consider this:

```
if( preg_match("^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+$", $email ) ) {
    // Whatever
}
```

Keep in mind, however, that this is really a poor-man's approach to validating an email address.  Email addresses can contain a lot more characters than those listed in the character class I provided.  Furthermore, it would also be possible to construct an invalid email address with those same character classes.  It doesn't even begin to deal with Unicode.  Using a regex to validate an email address is quite difficult.  Friedl takes a shot at it in Mastering Regular Expressions (O'Reilly), and his effort takes a 2KB regular expression pattern.  At best, this is only a basic sanity check.  It's not a secure means of verifying an email address.  At worst, it literally misses valid regexes, and still matches invalid ones.

There is the [mailparse_rfc822_parse_addresses](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mailparse-rfc822-parse-addresses.php) function which is more reliable in detecting and matching email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use preg_match to run the regular expression.

Now you're setting the $email = to the regular expression.

It could look like:

```
if ( preg_match("[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9]", $email ))
```

Also keep in mind when matching in an if you must use the `==` operator.

I believe best pratice would be to use a filter_var instead like:

```
if( ! filter_var( $email , FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL )) {
 // Failed.
}
```

Comment: Beating a dead horse here, but the regex itself is inadequate.  It would match the minimal case of `0@0` for example.  Or essentially anything that has a word character immediately to the left and right of `@`.  It would match`!@#$%^&*()_+1@1+_)(*&^%$#@!`, for example.  That's not a valid email address.

Comment: The regex was taken from OP's original post.

Answer (score 0):

Another way taken from: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585

```
function check_email_address($email) {
  // First, we check that there's one @ symbol, 
  // and that the lengths are right.
  if (!ereg("^[^@]{1,64}@[^@]{1,255}$", $email)) {
    // Email invalid because wrong number of characters 
    // in one section or wrong number of @ symbols.
    return false;
  }
  // Split it into sections to make life easier
  $email_array = explode("@", $email);
  $local_array = explode(".", $email_array[0]);
  for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($local_array); $i++) {
    if
(!ereg("^(([A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-][A-Za-z0-9!#$%&
↪'*+/=?^_`{|}~\.-]{0,63})|(\"[^(\\|\")]{0,62}\"))$",
$local_array[$i])) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  // Check if domain is IP. If not, 
  // it should be valid domain name
  if (!ereg("^\[?[0-9\.]+\]?$", $email_array[1])) {
    $domain_array = explode(".", $email_array[1]);
    if (sizeof($domain_array) < 2) {
        return false; // Not enough parts to domain
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($domain_array); $i++) {
      if
(!ereg("^(([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])|
↪([A-Za-z0-9]+))$",
$domain_array[$i])) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: The regex you supplied at the top is also inadequate.  There are many issues, not the least of which is the fact that the bare "dot" (not inside of any character class) can match any character at all, including `@`, which would lead to a totally invalid email address passing.

Comment: Thanks @DavidO, I just removed it from my answer!